# Finding the point of intersection of two curves. Integrating with respect to Y.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

I need to find the area between two curves, integrating with respect to $Y$. Is there a way to find the point where two curves intersect mathematically? My professor has only shown us by graphing the curves manually.
For example, $x = y^2-4y$ and $x= 2y-y^2$. Not asking anyone to do it.

Answer (score 3):

To find where $x=g(y)$ and $x=f(y)$ intersect, set $g(y)=f(y)$ and solve. For your example, your equation to solve will be a quadratic equation.

Comment: Its heartening to see to the point answers and exactly what the OP wants. +1